Real time smoothing using Savitzky-Golay method or any similar method with low phase lag
I have time series data that contains a lot of noise ( generated using geometric Brownian motion process ) and essentially I need a way to smooth this data in real time. During some tests I've done using Savitzky-Golay method and Whittaker-Eilers methods on past data, both methods performed well without much lag ( when applied on the whole sample dataset and not in real time ) introduced however once I started using this on an stream of data ( real time data ), both methods performed not as well. I understand how these methods work and I understand the reason behind bad performance on streaming/real time series data, but I am wondering if there is a way to adapt these methods ( i.e. modify window of Savitzky-Golay method or something similar ) or use another method better suited for this specific case ( smoothing data with low or no phase lag at all if possible during real time data streaming ).
I've found some potential solutions like in the following post: Savitzky-Golay filtering (not smoothing) in real time
but I am not sure I understand exactly how would this solve this issue.
Image below pretty much summarizes what happens while I process smoothing or apply filter to this data in real time:

Keep in mind that I am new to signal processing in general and please feel free to be as descriptive as you can if you will and if you are willing you can also post some images or even code, thanks!

Please edit your question for clarity.  When you say that these methods worked well on past data, without lag, was that because you were calculating each $y_k$ as a function of $x_{k-N},\ \cdots,\ x_k,\ \cdots,\ x{k+N}$?  Also, you say that you're measuring a process that is "like" a random walk.  Do you mean that it is a random walk, or that it's some low-pass filtering process with injected noise?  Do you have a model for this process that you can share?  I ask because throwing random low-pass filters at data may be better than nothing, but it is much worse than model-based smoothing.

I will, I see I am missing a couple of crucial details. I now updated the question with details but I will write here too in summary. I used geometric Brownian motion for generating data and it is random walk ( not low-pass filtering process or something related to that ). And I tested by applying filter to whole dataset ( I created experimental dataset sample of about 1000 elements generated from the gBm process ) and that's probably why I got really good results ( because on example Savitzky-Golay smoother had access to future values as well in the window ).

And I also agree with last point. That's a part of the reason I post this here, there are people more familiar in this field that would probably point me at least at the right direction related to the models/algorithms I could try for something like this.

If you need the data processed in realtime, you will have to use a fully causal method. A simple one-pole IIR lowpass could suffice, or for more computational expense, something like an alpha-beta filter might get you even less phase lag.
However, the less phase lag you can accept, the less attenuation ability the filter will have. That is just the way the physics works.

This comment summarizes this pretty well, thanks. I just want to ask do you have some paper or source related to types of filters you provided as additional example?
